# Solve for $X$: $4+2X > 7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for **$$4 + 2x > 7$$**

My answer was $1 \frac{1}{2}$, but I am not so sure it is right. Could anyone confirm it for me?  I need someone to solve the inequality.  The first step would be to subtract $4$ from both sides.

Comment: It is an inequality, so you cannot have just one answer.  You would have to have a spectrum of answers. Yiur answer is correct - just divide the answer that you get by subtracting 4 from each side to get tbe highest bound on the value of x.

Comment: That being said, 1/2 is not correct since $4+2(1/2) = 5 \not >7$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'll have

$$\begin{align}4+2x\gt 7&\iff 4+2x-4\gt 7-4\\&\iff 2x\gt 3\\&\iff 2x/2\gt 3/2\ \ (\because 2\gt 0)\\&\iff x\gt 3/2=1.5.\end{align}$$

Note that if $a\gt 0$, then
$$b\gt c\iff b/a\gt c/a.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Property $\bf1$:** If $x,y$ are two real numbers such that: $x>y$, we have that $x+\mathrm c>y+\mathrm c$ for every $\mathrm c$ in  $\Bbb R$.

---

**Property $\bf2$:** If $x,y$ are two real numbers such that: $x>y$, we have that $x\cdot\mathrm c>y\cdot\mathrm c$ for every positive $\mathrm c$ in  $\Bbb R$.

---

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
4+2x\gt 7&\overset{\mathbf{Pr. 1}}{\iff} 4+2x\color{red}{-4}\gt 7\color{red}{-4}\\\,\\
& \iff 2x \gt 3 \\ \,\\
& \overset{\mathbf{Pr. 2}}{\iff}2x\cdot\dfrac12 \gt 3\dfrac 12 \\ \, \\
& \iff x\gt 3/2=1.5
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after subtracting $ 4 $ to both sides

$$ 2x > 3 $$

Then divide $ 2 $ to both sides to solve for x:

$$ x > \frac{3}{2} $$ or $$ x > 1.5 $$